# Effect of doctype on css

Tags: html, css

When I do

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div style="width:100%;height:100%;background:blue;"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

the div fills the window

but if i add a doctype tag at the beginning

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div style="width:100%;height:100%;background:blue;"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

the div fills the width, but doesn't fill the height.

Any idea what's going on? I know I'm supposed to put doctype tags, I'm just wondering specifically it's doing in this case thats causing the different behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lack of doctype declaration triggers “quirks mode,” which means that browsers do different things to cope with the document, assuming it to be legacy code that may rely on features that existed in old browsers. Roughly speaking, “quirks mode” means that browser try to behave more or less like Internet Explorer 4. But they do it in different ways; I’ve composed an incomplete list of [what happens in “quirks mode.”](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) “Quirks mode” should only be used for legacy pages that need it; conversely, pages that work in “quirks mode” may fall apart in “standards mode,” and you get there just by adding a doctype declaration.

In your case, skipping the theory part here, you need to add some rules to make the div element fill the canvas in “standards mode”:

```
<style>
  head, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
</style>
```

and

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;background:blue; position: absolute;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read this you get ideas about doctype,
doctype is very important part in web designing

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/doctype.html

Comment: That W3Schools article has got a number of errors in it (surprise, surprise, it is W3Schools), the WDG article is out of date (and doesn't cover HTML 5 which the question uses) … and neither answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

When you add Doctype to you html page, you are instructing your browser to follow the standard specified by doctype. If its not specified, the browser will not know what kind of document it is.

You should always specify a `<!DOCTYPE>` in your page.

Some links to help you understand what doctype is and why is it important.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: That isn't what Doctypes do. Browsers know what kind of document it is because they care about the Content-Type header when trying to determine that, not the Doctype. That W3Schools article has lots of errors in it.

Comment: Ok, I did some more research on this, and found that doctype actually defines the version of your (X)HTML page is using. If the browser know which version is being used, it can use that specific version to parse the document and would not need to keep guessing how to parse elements of the document. The doctype will help in using the standard rendering mode, instead of the browser specific quirks mode. Also without the doctype, the content and the CSS cannot be validated.

Comment: The browser only uses an XHTML parser if the content-type says application/xhtml+xml, if it says text/html then it uses an HTML parser. The Doctype is only used for Quirks/Standards mode.

Comment: You certainly don't need a Doctype to validate CSS. CSS isn't even markup. (It can even be argued that you don't need one to validate (X)HTML if you are doing so against a schema).

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does. the problem is, the height of the body is not big enough, so the div's height will be as big as the body height.